# List files exceeding a certain size limit

Tags: ubuntu, files, find, size

I have an application structured in the form of a folder and several levels of subfolders.

I want to list all the files within my application's folder that are equal to or larger than *300KiB*. How do you do that from the command line?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
find /your/app/directory -size +300k
```